# Migrating machine from domain to workgroup, issues with file ownership

Tags: windows-xp, domain, migration, permissions

I followed the guide at http://msmvps.com/blogs/clustering/archive/2004/10/06/15096.aspx to move my laptop from a domain to a workgroup.

One thing caught my eye, and that is:
 - There's still a ton of records in the registry with the SID from the domain user
 - Files in C:\windows\system32 have owner set to that SID.

Questions:
 - How can I fix the issue re: the registry, or should I just leave it as it is?
 - Re: ownership of files, should I leave them owned by the SID, or change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you could use would be to select the top level folder (if possible) right click > properties > security tab > advanced > remove the option the inherit permissions and remove all entries and add your new username > owner tab > set yourself as the owner > hit apply and wait.

All being well this should resolve your problem.

Comment: That's one option... a) problem is that if there are different ownserhips below that, I would possibly have to do this sub folder by sub folder. b) What are the implications of having these files owned by a SID whose account no longer exists?

Comment: A) the method above would override any child permissions B) you would do this with a new local administrator account so it would be the owning SID.